# silverstripe 3 blog next and previous post

Tags: php, silverstripe

I'm trying to return the next (newer) and previous (older) BlogPost from the one I am currently viewing.

I have set this up on an extension:

```
<?php
class BlogPost_Extension extends DataExtension {

public function getBlogSibling($Mode = 'next') {
    if($Mode == 'next'){
        $pages = BlogPost::get()->filter(array(
        'ParentID' => $this->owner->ParentID,
        'PublishDate:GreaterThan' => $this->owner->PublishDate
        ))->Sort('PublishDate ASC')->limit(1);
    } elseif($Mode == 'prev'){
        $pages = BlogPost::get()->filter(array(
        'ParentID' => $this->owner->ParentID,
        'PublishDate:LessThan' => $this->owner->PublishDate
        ))->Sort('PublishDate DESC')->limit(1);
    }

    if ($pages->count()) {
        return $pages->First();
    }
    return false;
}

}
```

and using this in the template:

```
<% if $BlogSibling('next') %><a href="$BlogSibling('next').Link">newer story</a><% end_if %>
<% if $BlogSibling('prev') %><a href="$BlogSibling('prev').Link">older story</a><% end_if %>
```

But both return the same result, the next (newer) BlogPost - I'm sure its something stupid I'm overlooking....!:)

(silverstripe 3.1.4  /  blog module ~2.4)

Answer (score 2):

[Another (better) solution, found by munomono](http://gist.github.com/mediabeastnz/ebf1c91220f6375b7c8f)

---

You need to extend BlogPost_Controller and not the BlogPost. Than add the following functions

```
  public function PrevBlogPost() {
    $sort = $this->owner->Sort;
    $prevSort = $sort - 1;

    if($prev = $this->owner->Parent()->getBlogPosts()->find('Sort', $prevSort)) {
      return $prev;
    }
  }

  public function NextBlogPost() {
    $sort = $this->owner->Sort;
    $nextSort = $sort + 1;

    if($next = $this->owner->Parent()->getBlogPosts()->find('Sort', $nextSort)) {
      return $next;
    }
  }
```

In your template

```
  <% if $PrevBlogPost %>
    <a href="$PrevBlogPost.Link" title="$PrevBlogPost.Title">
      <i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>vorheriger Beitrag
    </a>
  <% end_if %>
  <% if $NextBlogPost %>
    <a href="$NextBlogPost.Link" title="$NextBlogPost.Title">
      nächster Beitrag<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
    </a>
  <% end_if %>
```

Of course you could combine those functions into one.

Comment: Just using a single sort number isn't going to work reliably. Imagine you have some unpublished posts that have the `Sort` number you're querying? I think you should search for `> $sort` or `< $sort` and return the first result from that…

Comment: Just sorting on Sort doesn't take into account the true order of blog posts, since they are in order of PublishDate, not Sort.

Comment: But @galilee the idea is that you set the order in the SiteTree as you want them to be displayed, so the sort order should be used for this purpose

Comment: But for a blog, the sort is not usually by Sort - but by the date the article was published - everything else in the blog (ie recent posts etc) sorts by PublishDate, so I need this to as well....